# Adding an existing angular project to an existing NX project

Tags: angular, react-native, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have an existing NX project name `myorg`. which have already three application name `one`, `two`, `three`. I am able to create a new application (name: `four`) into that NX project (`myorg`) by the command:

```js
ng g @nrwl/schematics:application four
```

but I want to add an existing angular project (name: 'todos') into the existing NX project (name: `myorg`). What is the process ?

Note: I am able to add NX to an existing angular project by command:

```js
ng add @nrwl/schematics
```